# top margin issue for windows phone 7 apps on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

The windows phone 7 application which I developed using 7.1 SDK occupies the entire screen on wp7. But the same application when opened in Windows Phone 8 shows some extra margin on top because of which my app was not able use the space on top. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP7 only supports only one resolution (480x800).

For 480x800 WP8 devices that's obviously fine.

For 1280x768 devices this scales fine as this is the same aspect ratio.

However 1280x720 devices have a different aspect ratio which leaves the black bars at the top of the screen.

The only way to fix this is to upgrade your project to WP8 using the WP8 SDK (whilst watching out for any subtle issues that may bring).